# Como resolver erro de estilização nos options do Select Option que aparece com erro no Firefox

Tags: php, jquery, css, css3

No Firefox versão 48.0, esta dando erro na estilização nos options do Select Option.

Segue o código:

```
<div class="buscaCodigo">

  <div class="form">
  <br /> <br />
   <h2>Entre abaixo com o código</h2>
   <form action="busca.php" method="post">
     <input type="hidden" name="acao"  value="buscaCodigo" />
     <br /> <br />
     <label>Código</label><input type="text" class="typeTextMedio" id="codigo"  name="codigo" required />
    <input type="submit" value="Pequisar" class="btnPesquisa" />
     <br /> <br />
   </form> 
   </div>

  <div class="fechar">
    <img src="_img/btn-close.png" style="width:50px;" />
  </div>

</div>

<div class="buscaImovel"><br />
  <h1 class="h1Centralizado">Pesquise pelo imóvel que deseja</h1>

  <div style="height:10px;"></div>

  <div class="divBusca">

  <form action="busca.php"  method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="acao" value="buscaPrincipal">

    <div class="camposBusca">
      <?php  $tiposImoveis = $tiposDao->pesquisaTipos(); ?>
      <select multiple="multiple" id="tipo" name="tipo[]" size="1" required>
        <option value="Indiferente">Indiferente</option>
        <?php
             if ($tiposImoveis == null) {
                 echo "<option value=''>Não há tipo cadastrado ainda!</option>";
             } else {
               foreach ($tiposImoveis as $tipoImovel) {

                   echo "<option value='".$tipoImovel->getIdTipos()."'>".$tipoImovel->getNome()."</option>";
               }
             }
           ?>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="camposBusca">
      <?php  $bairrosImoveis = $imoveisDao->pesquisaBairros("Muriaé"); ?>
      <select multiple="multiple" id="bairro" name="bairro[]" size="1" required>
        <option value="Indiferente">Indiferente</option>
        <?php
             if ($bairrosImoveis == null) {
                 echo "<option value=''>Não há tipo cadastrado ainda!</option>";
             } else {
               foreach ($bairrosImoveis as $bairrosImovel) {
                   echo "<option value='".$bairrosImovel."'>".$bairrosImovel."</option>";
               }
             }
           ?>
      </select>      
    </div>

    <div class="camposBusca">
      <input type="submit" class="btnPesquisa" value="Pesquisar"  />
    </div>

  </form>
  </div>

  <div style="height:15px;"></div>

  <div class="alternativaEscolha">
    <a href="buscaAvancada.php">
      <label class="labelGrande" style="background-color:#CCC; font-weight:bold; color:#000;">Busca Avançada</label>
    </a> 
  </div>

  <div class="alternativaEscolha"> 
    <!--abrir popUp--> 
        <label class="labelGrande" style="background-color:#CCC; font-weight:bold; color:#000">Busca por Código</label> 
  </div>

</div>
```

Que no firefox gera a seguinte imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No Chorme e no IE aparece corretamente,

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse select que sai errado no firefox, tem seus options estilizados também errado.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao passo que no Chrome e no IE essa estilização vem correta:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como resolver isso?

Comment: Passe o link do site e posso corrijir, ou veja sobre mozilla css

Comment: ainda não esta publicado. Teria algum código que eu poderia postar que ajudasse?

Comment: Entendo, coloca o codigo de exemplo para eu ver do site www.codepen.io, jsfiddle.net ou www.codeply.com ... quiser meu skype?!

Comment: fiz melhor, coloquei em uma outra hospedagem que tenho: http://funerariasaopedro.net.br/caimoveismuriae.com.br/index.php

Comment: Qual é a versão seu firefox? aqui nova versão esta certinho, é cuidado div do pai sem display e filho com display, e corrija o pai div `.divBusca { display: flex; }` e outro filho div `.camposBusca { display: inline-flex; }`. Se está usando inline-block e use pai block. Me avise e ajudo outra vez.

Comment: Eu, particularmente, não gosto muito do jquery-ui, eu prefiro o select2 https://plugins.jquery.com/select2/ ou o chosen https://plugins.jquery.com/chosen/
Talvez esse fiquem melhor no firefox

Comment: firefox 48.0 que eu uso. também está dando o erro

Comment: diminui o texto e coube

Comment: @CarlosRocha Hum... não estou dizendo jquery-ui, é CSS. Já testou q passei o código? para reduzir o fonte é beleza.

Comment: Já testei, deu no mesmo. entendi ser css.

Comment: Tente utilizar `vertical-align: middle`.